# Draw a line in a specific angle (dynamic)

Tags: android

I want to draw a circle and that activity must receive values (in degrees). I would draw lines on this circle and will have the opportunity to draw points on it.

[image]

If you can help me it would be great :)

Comment: Sorry but this is an English site.

Comment: i want to draw 3 lines at a specific angles thanks

Comment: And what have you tried? Pleas read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and all the links on the bottom of the article. Add also things you've tried so we could help you. Now is this question to broad.

Answer (score 0):

I tried This :

```
public class DiagObstActivity extends Activity {
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.diagobstacles_main);
    int radius;
    radius = 200;
    final ImageView imgCircle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgCircle);
     Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(getResources().getColor((R.color.blue)));
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(500,500,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
    canvas.drawCircle(bmp.getWidth() / 2, bmp.getHeight() / 2, radius, paint);

    RectF rectF = new RectF(50, 20, 100, 80);
    canvas.drawOval(rectF, paint);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawArc(rectF, 180, 0, true, paint);

    imgCircle.setImageBitmap(bmp);
  }
}
```

but the result is 2 circles [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9kUr.png)
i am new thanks for ur help :)